# Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::where() in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.4` where I'm having following query:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$tasks = $user->tasks;
$tasks->count = $tasks->count();
$tasks->completedCount = $tasks->where('status', '=', 'Closed')->count();
$tasks->investorCount = $tasks->where('task_id', '=', 'Investor Targets')->count();
$tasks->investorCompletedCount = $tasks->where([
    ['task_id', '=', 'Investor Targets'],
    ['status', '=', 'Closed'],
])->get()->count();
$tasks->researchCount = $tasks->where('task_id', '=', 'Research Targets')->count();
$tasks->researchCompletedCount = $tasks->where([
    ['task_id', '=', 'Research Targets'],
    ['status', '=', 'Closed'],
])->get()->count();
dd($tasks);
```

I'm getting following error;

> Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::where()

In the line

```
$tasks->investorCompletedCount = $tasks->where([
        ['task_id', '=', 'Investor Targets'],
        ['status', '=', 'Closed'],
    ])->get()->count();
```

My syntax is also correct, I don't know from where this problem is coming. Help me out in this.

Comment: I think you are trying to use a "where" of Query Builder in a Collection, which has another method called "where".

Comment: You need to use two `where` caluses for your conditions. In collection, `where` clause only takes two parameters. Take a look here.... https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_where shows the correct syntax for using the where method on a collection. The error says it's a collection, not a query builder instance.

Comment: You can not use multiple array condition in `Collection` you have to write `where` condition two times. You can use it in `Query Builder`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code

```
$tasks->investorCompletedCount = $tasks->where([
    ['task_id', '=', 'Investor Targets'],
    ['status', '=', 'Closed'],
])->get()->count();
```

needs to be rewritten as

```
$tasks->investorCompletedCount = $tasks->where('task_id', 'Investor Targets')
->where('status', 'Closed')->count();
```

The problem is you are confusing the method `where` of an `Eloquent query construction`

(https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where)

with the method `where`of a `Collection`

(https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_where).

Actually you are trying to use a `Collection` as if it were a `query builder`, because you also try to perform a `get`.

Answer (score 1):

> You are mixing the `Eloquent where` with a `Collection where`.

Change your code to this:-

```
$tasks->investorCompletedCount = $tasks->where('task_id','Investor Targets')
                                       ->where('status', 'Closed')->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
$tasks->investorCompletedCount = $tasks
->where(['task_id' => 'Investor Targets','status' => 'Closed'])
->get()
->count();
```